# After collectstatic no css for admin page

Tags: python, css, django

Here is the setup of my setting.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')


STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

I do `collectstatic` . Everything looks fine, except admin css is no working anymore.

Comment: Are you running with `DEBUG = True` or `False? What version of Django? What is your `STATIC_ROOT`? Are you using the staticfiles app?

Comment: DEBUG = True; Django = 1.7; forgot to include that - editet.

Comment: collectstatic is really only for moving static media in to the directory specified by `STATIC_ROOT` for deployment to your production environment. It's not needed when developing locally.Is the admin CSS missing in your production or development environment?

Comment: It is missing in development environment

Comment: Are you using the staticfiles app? If so, what's your `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting?

Comment: i am not sure whether I am using staticfiles app. I have django.contrib.staticfiles in my setting.py. And I didn't set STATICFILES_DIRS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have some settings missing. When you're leveraging the [staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) app, you need to instruct Django where to serve those files from in development - when `DEBUG = True`. When `DEBUG = False` you need to use Apache, Nginx or some other Http server to serve your static media - not Django.

You need to have the following settings in place:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    . . .
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('/path/to/your/development/static/directory'),
)

# this is where manage.py collectstatic will copy *all* static media to
STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/your/production/static/direcotry'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'  # or whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem... it turned out that I had added STATICFILES_FINDERS in my settings and commented out the AppDirectoriesFinder, thus it didn't collect up all my apps including admin app... That could be one possible cause for missing admin css files ;) My STATICFILES_FINDERS:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
    'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
)
```